# My Navbar in mobile view is not woking in React using useRef hook

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, use-ref

I am trying to make my navbar responsive for mobile in Vite reactjs using useRef hook but its not wokring.

I tried to use useRef hook to make it responsive by toggling classList "responsive_nav" on nav tag in my NavBar component.
I have 2 buttons from react icons, FaTimes and FaBars for navbar in mobile, and the classes are toggled with useRef().

here's my NavBar component:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import "../styles/styles.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { FaBars, FaTimes } from "react-icons/fa";

function NavBar() {
  const navRef = useRef();
  const showNavBar = () => {
    navRef.current.classList.toggle("responsive_nav");
  };
  return (
    <>
      <nav ref={navRef}>
        <div className="itemL">
          <Link to="#">mjshubham21</Link>
        </div>
        <div className="itemR">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="#">Home</Link>
            </li>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <button className="nav-btn nav-close-btn" onClick={showNavBar}>
        <FaTimes />
      </button>
      <button className="nav-btn" onClick={showNavBar}>
        <FaBars />
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

export default NavBar;

//Here's CSS for Navbar:

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1.1rem 0.8rem;
  height: 1.1rem;
  z-index: 200;
}



.nav-btn {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
  right: 2rem;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

@media (max-width: 450px) { //Is my media query correct or shall it change the unit??
  .nav-btn {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 1.5rem;
    transition: 250ms;
    transform: translateY(-100vh);
  }

  nav .responsive_nav {
    transform: none;
  }

  .nav-close-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2rem;
    right: 2rem;
    z-index: 9999;
  }

  nav a {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you include your styles as well in the question

Comment: Do you mean CSS of it?? I have, please scroll down...

Comment: [Here's the codesandbox link...](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/mjshubham21/Mjshubham21Portfolio/master?workspaceId=fe256bc6-8c9b-4e90-91aa-223661878145) to the whole project, Relevant is NavBar component and styles.css nav section and media query is at the end...

Comment: Your codesandbox link doesn't work. Can you create a new one?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't allowing changes and I pushed some... [Here's the new link](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/mjshubham21/Mjshubham21Portfolio/master?workspaceId=fe256bc6-8c9b-4e90-91aa-223661878145&file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FNavBar.jsx) but I used chatGPT yesterday and solved a ton...

Comment: but for now my close and hamburger menu icons aren't yet toggling and when I click on link it doesn't work!!